# Can't connect new Macbook Pro browser to Internet

Tags: macos, network, safari, wifi, internet

Browsing through WiFi to Internet worked perfect at my work location.  At home now my Safari almost always shows "You Are Not Connected to the Internet" Sometimes it shows a page (eg. Yahoo.com) but then same error happens.

Connects to WiFi LAN OK.  Connects to Ethernet LAN ok and pings other laptops.

My old macbook, physically next to it, browses Internet by WiFi LAN ok.

What I've tried: restarting mac, erasing Safari history, renewing wifi tcp/ip lease, restarted WiFi LAN router, a different WiFi LAN, Google browser.

Internet WiFi connection is with Verizon gateway.

UPDATE 2/24/2023:
Browsing works at home if I change Network Settings > Ethernet TCP/IP ipv4 from manual back to DHCP.  (I need manual so that my Windows laptop can remote control mac by Ethernet LAN.)

Comment: Please [edit] the question with the output of `ipconfig getpacket enX | grep domain` where X is the integer of your WiFi adapter device. To get this info, use the command `networksetup -listallhardwareports | grep Wi-Fi -A3` compare that with the DNS settings in Network settings.  Reply to this comment with @Allan so I’m notified.

Comment: @Allan domain_name_server (ip_mult): {192.168.0.1}

Comment: Your router is acting as a DNS server.  Are the DNS settings correct in the router?  Do you have any DNS servers manually configured on either router or Mac?

Comment: I don't know.  WiFi router is Eero v6 BASE with Ethernet connection to nearby Verizon wireless 5G gateway. On mac I set Ethernet for static IP. Another answer said to try setting DNS Serversr to google 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 but it didn't help; and I left those.

Comment: Set everything to be automatically configured.  I’ve yet to find a compelling reason to use Google’s DNS over your ISP’s DNS.

Comment: I removed google DNS.  Then, I changed Ethernet status IP back to DHCP and not browsing is ok. But I don't understand why manual Ethernet IP (169.254.55.55) prevents browsing.  My other Intel Mac on this same WiFi is set for static IP 169.254.111.111 without problem. (New mac is M2).

Comment: I don’t see how that’s possible.  169.xxx.yyy.zzz is a self assigned, non-routable address.

Comment: I've been remote controlling old mac for over a year from Windows, both using static IP's 169.254.33.33 (windows) and mac 169.254.111.111 (mac) Sub.. mask 255.255.0.0 without any problem, using TeamViewer.  And this does in fact work with new M2 mac but only 100 miles away at company HQ. I brought mac home, no more browsing unless I remove manual Ethernet setting.

Comment: Yes, it will work locally and if you connect through a VPN, it will also work because the VPN gets an IP from the corporate server.  TeamViewer uses an agent on the computer to connect, but I don’t have all the details on that one.